# Best way to call function on every object in array? Without for loop?

Tags: php, arrays, object, array-map

I'm curious if there's a better way to do what I'm doing. I'm fairly new to php so I'm interested in what others think who have spent more time with the language.

**What I want to do:** call a function on every object in an array

**What I'm doing:**

```
array_map(function($object) { $object->loadEvents(); }, $patients);
```

This is fine, and it works. I could also use a **for loop**,

**Why I'm asking:** I've become accustomed to not using for loops when I don't have too, so I figured out a way to use **array_map**. The thing is, every where I look, it seems people are using **array_map** to map results to a new array. When I basically want the functionality of **array_map** but without the return values.

Is there a better way? Outside this and a for loop? Is a for loop a better way?

Comment: Why are you so afraid of for loops? At the end `array_map()` will also use an internal loop to go through the array values. Also you might want to look at `array_walk()`

Comment: `foreach` is the usual way.

Comment: As @Rizier123 suggests, `array_walk()` is the version of `array_map()` that doesn't build a new array.

Comment: If you try to use something just because it seems fashionable, you're going to have a bad time. Just use the best tool for the job. If a loop is the simplest and cleanest solution, use that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual idiom in PHP for looping over an array is the `foreach` operator. `array_walk` and `array_map` can be used, but they didn't become common idioms because until relatively recent versions of PHP creating anonymous functions was inconvenient. Prior to PHP 5.3, you had to call `create_function()` to create a function on the fly. So `array_walk` and `array_map` were usually only used when there's a named function that does what you want, e.g.

```
$array = array_map('trim', $array);
```

But even now that you can use `function` to create anonymous functions, many people find

```
array_walk($array, function($x) {
    ...
});
```

less readable than

```
foreach ($array as $xx) {
    ...
}
```

`array_map` tends to be used more than `array_walk` because it can be used as part of a larger expression. With `foreach` you would have to use one loop to push onto a result array, then follow it with code to operate on that array.

Comment: This actually didn't work for me because I'm changing the instances with the function loadEvents. Apparently there's a problem with references and array_walk, so many a for loop is just easiest in this case. I appreciate the help though.

Comment: I don't think there should be any issue with objects and `array_walk`. I had the arguments to `array_walk` backwards in my answer, maybe that was the problem?

Comment: Oh yeah, that was the problem! Thanks a lot, works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with using a loop? That's the exact purpose it's designed for.

```
foreach ($patients as $patient) {
    $patient->loadEvents();
}
```

Simple and clear to everyone. What is the point in writing verbose code to achieve the same job, just because it seems "cool" or what everyone is doing?

> I've become accustomed to not using for loops when I don't have to, so I figured out a way to use array_map.

You are using `array_map()` incorrectly for the sake of an abitrary rule you've set yourself that you won't use a loop?

Comment: This seems like more of just a comment. I agree with it but you basically ignored the question and left out the obvious answer of `array_walk`.

Comment: I'm not using anything. No one said once there was a problem with a for loop, there isn't. 

The question was asked to gain knowledge.

Comment: @nerdlyist Well I haven't ignored the question at all. It literally starts with *"I'm curious if there's a better way to do what I'm doing."* and my answer is yes, use a `foreach` loop rather than `array_map` which is not fit for purpose, and `array_walk` which is basically a grander way of doing the same thing as a straightforward `foreach` loop in this case. The `foreach` is clearly more readable and dies the exact job required, and programming is about finding optimal, efficient and tidy solutions to problems.

Comment: @KristoferDoman You literally asked in your question *"Is a for loop a better way?"* and also said *"I've become accustomed to not using for loops when I don't have too, so I figured out a way to use array_map"* which makes no sense from a programming perspective if you are trying to write good code.

Comment: @BadHorsie I personally find foreach less readable, so there's nothing clear there. You're just arguing to argue, I'm done.

Comment: @KristoferDoman I was just explaining my answer, I didn't realise you would be so offended. It's your code - whatever makes you happy.